# Touchmove event only starts when user moves their first finger

Tags: javascript, android, multi-touch

I'm working on trying to develop a controller webapp. I have an analog stick one side and face button on the other.

I'm using a canvas and touch events (start move and end)

Im testing with Chrome on a nexus 4.

I'm after running into [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=135102#makechanges)

Which is basically only the first finger you press down is able to trigger the first touchmove event. Once the first touchmove happens it tracks touch movements on both fingers

Steps to repo would be:

- Press finger 1 down on the screen and hold it (do not move) - Touch start Event happens
- Press finger 2 down on the screen and hold it - Touch start event happens
- Move finger 2 - No touch move event
- Move finger 1 - Touch move event happens
- Move finger 2 - Touch move event happens

Is there anything i can do to work around this issue?

If anyone needs me to mock up an example I can.

Thanks

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the multitouch interface itself, thus theres not much you can do in your code. Maybe you can implement the touchmove event on your own, but thats way out of the standard solutions, and not performance efficent at all. If you are interested and need help, I can post an answer about how to do so.

Comment: @derylius Chrome seem to have implemented a fix for this, so hopefully it will show up on our phones eventually!

It would be interesting to see your solution, but I do not need for my project. Thanks though!

Comment: I looked after a bit just for the sake of fun, and found 2 possible solutions: 
the first is to trigger a touch end event on every touchstart and figure out the relation between the touchstart with your own algorith to simulate touchmove, but its probably not going to work, but if someone have time and interested, can try and prove me wrong; the second idea would probably work, really slowly using 1px divs generated over the canvas, and listening to their touchenter event and then again using your own algorithm to simulate the movements. But for those who read this, DON'T DO IT!